# Campos personalizados no cadastro de usuário

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Olá,

Preciso de um plugin pra criar campos personalizados no cadastro de usuário e depois exibir essas informações cadastradas. Por ex. queria um campo de CPF, Endereço, Telefone, etc.

Até encontrei um plugin, ele está criando um campo, mas não descobri uma forma de ‘trazer’ essas informações. Caso alguém conheça, o nome do plugin é User Registration Aide.

Alguém conhece um plugin que faça algo parecido com isso? Se tiver como, também necessito fazer esse cadastro fora do painel do wordpress, como uma página normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use o Advanced Custom Field

você cria o tipo de campo que quiser... e depois para recuperar a informação é bem simples seria algo como the_field('cpf', 'user_' . $user_id);